# Is it possible to find XSS vulnerabilities using FindBugs in NetBeans

Tags: java

My assignment is to find 3 and fix 2 vulnerabilities in java source code. So far I have found sql injection vulnerabilities using findbugs in netbeans and now I need to find xss vulnerabilities. Please Help!!!

Comment: How the hell are we supposed to help you without even looking at your code?!

Comment: So research what a XSS vulnerability is and what to look for. Not sure how on earth we're supposed to help with the information given. Please **do not** just dump the code here and ask us to find the vulnerabilities though. Please read *carefully*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here Moron can you not read..Is it possible to find xss vulnerabilities with FindBugs was the question..If u have nothing good to say then shut your mouth..Jesus Christ I hate people like you.

Answer (score 0):

HP Fortify Static code analyzer identifies XSS vulnerabilities in code.

More information is at : 
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/static-code-analysis-sast/